# TypeScript type for document.createElementNS

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to figure out what type to use for `title`.

```js
let text: String = `${this.altText || this.defaultText}`;

title = document.createElementNS(this.svgns, "title");
title.innerHTML = text;
```

The only thing that comes close is `let title: Element;` but `title.innerHTML` generates the following error:

```
Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.ts(2322)
```

I assume this might need an interface defined but I've just started with TypeScript and still trying to figure out the nuances.

Edit: added text declaration

Comment: I added the text declaration to the code snippet. It is String so that's not quit the answer. There seems to be a lack of information in general on svgs and TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might've set wrong, though looking similar, type for the text variable (but we can't see it from the snippet you provided).

> Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>     'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.ts(2322)

According to the error quote, I would guess that the text variable has the **String** type (pay attention to the first capital letter) and the **title.innerHTML** has the **string** type (pay attention to the first lower case letter).

Using the **string** type for the **text** variable should help.